QT creator can't seem to find the module plugin for a separate directory
I'm relatively new to QT and I've been struggling with keeping the files I use for creating my project organized.
Currently I'm trying to store the backend c++ files of my project into a separate folder within the project as can be seen in the picture.
Picture of the folder structure
However when trying to access the library from the Screen01.ui.qml file, I receive the following error log:
Error as it appears in the terminal
The backend c++ files have the QML_ELEMENT property and it works if I store them in the same content folder. So I'm really stumped as to why it doesn't work for when I store it into a separate folder. I surmise that I have to alter the CMakeLists.txt and I tried several things, but I really have no clue on how to approach this and I feel like I should ask some help in order to understand this more properly.

One way can be using QML modules. The process is adding something like the following in the related CMakeLists in the content folder
qt_add_library(Content STATIC)
qt_add_qml_module(Content 
   URI "contents"
   VERSION 1.0
   QML_FILES
       App.qml
       Screen01.ui.qml // maybe should be considered a Resource?!       
   )

making it known to the main CMakeLists
add_subdirectory(content)

target_link_libraries(YourApp PRIVATE
    Contentplugin
)

and finally, introduce it the header of main.cpp.
Q_IMPORT_QML_PLUGIN(constentsPlugin)

Then all QML libraries inside it, can be accessed easily with
import contents

This method is a bit tricky, especially around naming conventions. So, be careful of plugin suffix and capital letters. Furthermore, some warning are gonna be shown in QML where the module is imported, which wont stop the app from running and can be ignored.
If there are so many QMLs use try this way, otherwise you can always just add content folder top of the desired one.
import "../content"

